# Change a specific text inside a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the code below, I would like to use jQuery to only change the words "Going for" to "Highest bid:". The only way I know how is to use `replaceWith` to produce something like this: `$('#wp-bidcontainerleft').replaceWith('new word');` but that wouldn't work since I'm not replacing everything within the div.

```
<div id="wp-bidcontainerleft">
  Going for
  <br>
  $101.00
</div>
```

What would be the simplest method of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contents` method:

```
$('#wp-bidcontainerleft').contents().each(function(i, v){
    if (i === 0) {
        this.textContent
        ? this.textContent = 'new word' // non-ie browsers
        : this.innerText = 'new word';  // crazy ie
        return false // stop executing each method
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DPVTg/

Answer (score 1):

You have to get `.contents()` which also retrieves the text-only child elements and then replace the first child

```
$('#wp-bidcontainerleft').contents().eq(0).replaceWith(document.createTextNode('Highest bid:'));
```

Comment: Actually the name of the method is `contents`, have you tested your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$(function () {
    $('#wp-bidcontainerleft').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace('Going for', 'Highest bid:');
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```